# c# setting datasource to datagridview, updating source datatable

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding

i have a datagridview whose datasource is attached to a datatable

how do i update the datatable and then make sure to refresh the datagridview to reflect the changes in the datasource? or do i need to do this at all?

Comment: You might want to Google for some tutorials on databinding.  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/databinding_tutorial.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do this.  If you delete or update a row in the datatable, the bound datagridview should update its display to reflect the changes.